# Нет функции в библиотеке SDL 2

Tags: c, sdl, sdl2

Все доброго времени суток)) Вот у меня возникла проблема. Компилятор ругается что не видит функции SDL_Flip(); инклужу библиотеку

```
# include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

Все функции отрабатывает отлично. В чем проблема понять не могу /
Насколько я понимаю она и не должна здесь быть ведь функция с первой версии / Кто что может посоветовать?

Comment: особо не вникая в суть, а просто из гугла: http://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide#line-453

Comment: Можно посоветовать найти туториал по SDL2, а не по SDL1.

Answer (score 2):

В sdl2 нужно создавать renderer, и использовать такие функции.

```
SDL_RenderClear ( render );
SDL_RenderPresent ( render );
```